# Como usar o tabs-bottom no ionic V1

Tags: ionic

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo em ionic v1 porém não estou conseguindo colocar a tabs no botton no android, por padrão no ios ele já sai no bottom.

Segue o meu código e uma imagem de exemplo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<ion-view id="page1">
<ion-tabs class="tabs-royal tabs-icon-bottom" id="tabsController-tabs1">
<ion-tab title="Empreendimentos" icon="ion-map" href="#/page1/page2" 
id="tabsController-tab1">
<ion-nav-view name="tab1"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>
<ion-tab title="Agenda" icon="ion-ios-contact-outline" href="#/page1/page3" 
id="tabsController-tab2">
<ion-nav-view name="tab2"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>
<ion-tab title="Condomínios" icon="ion-android-pin" href="#/page1/page4" 
id="tabsController-tab3">
<ion-nav-view name="tab3"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: ionic v1 é com angular ou com angular**JS**? Se for angularJS, veja esta resposta https://stackoverflow.com/a/27915387/1518921 ou esta https://stackoverflow.com/a/36363311/1518921 se for Angular (sem js) veja esta resposta: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38468355/1518921

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Guilherme consegui resolver com os links acima!